# Gauge Invariance and the solutions of the equations

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-invariance

The equations for the potentials in E. M. are

$$\nabla^2 \phi + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\nabla \cdot \textbf{A} \right) = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} \tag{1}$$

$$\nabla^2 \textbf{A} - \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 \textbf{A} }{\partial t^2}-\nabla \left( \nabla \cdot \textbf{A} + \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial t} \right) = - \mu_0 \textbf{J}, \tag{2}$$

introducing Lorenz's gauge $$ \nabla \cdot \textbf{A} + \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial t} = 0 \tag{3}$$ one gets the much simpler equations

$$\nabla^2 \phi - \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} \tag{4}$$

$$\nabla^2 \textbf{A} - \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 \textbf{A} }{\partial t^2} = - \mu_0 \textbf{J} \tag{5}$$

Pretend we solve the equations (4) and (5) and get a solution for the potentials, do these solutions necessarily solve (1), (2) and (3) as well?  My guess would be no because the fields we can derive from $\phi$ and $\textbf{A}$ solutions of (4) and (5) must be the same we would get from the solutions of (1) and (2), but the potentials are changed by the gauge transformation and they can not be solutions of (1) and (2) anymore.

Comment: (3)+(4)+(5)=(1)+(2)

Comment: Only if the solution of (4) and (5) also solves (3).

Comment: for any $\lambda$ satisfying $\nabla ^2 \lambda - c^{-2}\ddot \lambda=0$ and in (4),(5) $\mathbf{A},\phi$ replaced with $\mathbf{A} +\nabla \lambda$ and $\phi - \dot\lambda$ will also satisfy (1) and (2) otherwise (1) + (2) be equivalent with (3)+(4)+(5) and appropriate boundary conditions.

Comment: @hyportnex So that means the solutions to (4), (5) $\phi$, $\textbf{A} $ without the gauge shifting function $\lambda $ do not themselves solve equations (1) and (2), right? In order to make them solve those equations we need to add $-\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial t} $, $\nabla \lambda$ with a specific \lambda. Right?

Comment: just as adding an arbitrary constant to the electrostatic potential does not change the $\mathbf {E}$ field any $\lambda$ satisfying the wave equation will keep the $\mathbf {E,H}$ fields the same

Comment: Sure, but I'm not really concerned about the fields I'm concerned about whether the potentials derived from (4) and (5), as purely mathematical functions, apart from their physical meaning solve the equations (1) and (2) as well